# Define pairings and assign values

Tags: python, python-2.7

Imagine a game in which 4 agents playing in pairs has to show signals to their partners for 3 rounds. In each round we change pairs.
We assign the initial signals that each participant produces randomly:

```
Sen1_part1 = random.choice ("ABCD")
Sen1_part2 = random.choice ("ABCD")
Sen1_part3 = random.choice ("ABCD")
Sen1_part4 = random.choice ("ABCD")
```

Now, we create a dictionary for each participant where we want to store the signals seen. For example, if signal A was assigned to participant 2, in the experiment this means that he has shown signal A to his partner. If for example, in round 1, participant 1 has played with participant 2, we will want to store in Mem_part1 the A signal with value 1. We always want to keep in the dictionary the signal assigned to the partner).

```
Mem_part1 = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0, "D": 0}
Mem_part2 = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0, "D": 0}
Mem_part3 = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0, "D": 0}
Mem_part4 = {"A": 0, "B": 0, "C": 0, "D": 0}
```

Therefore, we need to define somehow the pairings throughout the four rounds. It had occurred to me that through a list (or with an array in numpy). Something like that:

```
Order_comparements = ([[1,2,3,4] # 1 plays with 2, 3 plays with 4
                       [1,3,2,4] # 1 with 3, 2 with 4
                       [1,4,2,3] # 1 with 4, 2 with 3
```

However, I do not know how a list or an array might be useful for defining pairings order in the game.

In short, we want our program to be able to define a pairing order, and according to those pairings, store the randomly assigned letter in the corresponding dictionary as a value.

Comment: Since you are a beginner, you should know that you are using a *list*. A python `array` can refer to the data structure available in the `array` module, or perhaps more commonly, a `numpy` array. While a `list` is an array of pointers underneath the hood, it is best to use the proper terminology so as to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I dint get what do you meant by `A solution that takes into account the assigned order in which participants play, given by the matrix.`

Comment: Yes, to me it seems you can just keep track of the pair order separately, and the pair result. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I mean that, in the first round, in this example, participant 1 plays with 2, participant 3 plays with 4, because is the order assigned in the list pair_order. But we could change this order to [1,3,2,4]. So we want to built up a program in which we are able to change this order.

Comment: Yes, maybe it's confusing, I'm a beginner. I wanna simulate a game in which 4 participants play in pairs, in each round. And store the values in a dictionary. And I guess we could control the order in which participants play with a list. I'm try to learn thinking this kind of examples. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried to better define my question. Hope it helps.